# How to move navbar toggle button to right on small screens

Tags: toggle, navbar, mobile-website

Navbar toggle button is coming in center on small screen. how can i move it to right??
i tried few ways but it is not working. However the navbar works fine on medium and large screens.

here is my code:
""

```
                <!-- ========================= Theme Feature Page Menu ======================= -->
                <nav class="navbar float-right navbar-expand-lg navbar-expand-md theme-main-menu">
                   <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                   <div class="navbar-header">
                     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle float-xs-right collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                      
                       <span class="sr-only">Menu</span>
                       Menu
                       <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                     </button>
                   </div>
                   <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
                     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
                        
                        <li class="dropdown-holder"><a href="#">ABOUT COLLEGE</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li><a href="CollegeProfile.php" class="tran3s">College Profile</a></li>
                                <li><a href="PrincipalsMessage.php" class="tran3s">Principals Message</a></li>
                                <li><a href="VisionMission.php" class="tran3s">Vision & Mission</a></li>
                                <li><a href="CommitteeList.php" class="tran3s">Committee List</a></li>
                                <li><a href="PhotoGallery.php" class="tran3s">Photo Gallery</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        
                        <li><a href="Contact.php">CONTACT</a>
                     </ul>
                   </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                </nav> <!-- /.theme-feature-menu -->
            </div>
        </header> <!-- /.theme-main-header -->""
```

[image]

Comment: The menu moves to right when it is expanded but comes in center when collapsed

Comment: in the `nav` tag, what happens when you add `navbar-expand-sm` ?

Comment: @CybeX Nothing happens. stays same

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible, but on Google Chrome, use dev tools to change your screen size (https://imgur.com/yArsGrB) till you see this occurring, using object inspector, find the element and play around with alignment, etc settings. That is the only suggestion I can offer.

Comment: it seems like i am using bootstrap.min.css version 5 file instead of version 3. i changed the file and the menu moved to extreme right as needed. However i would like to keep using version 5 file instead. so what should i do now

Comment: glad you got that figured. Supporting 2 different library versions is not recommended. Usually one sticks to the latest version. Regardless, if you wish to stick to v3 - you will need to have a look at why the menu goes to the right hand side as required. By this, I mean looking at the menu's css classes and styles and determine which is causing it to perform as needed, then transfer these into your own custom css class which you then apply to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Within the desired CSS file of yours declare definition sizes and then use `float: right;`

Example:

```
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767px) {
.navigation.navbar {
    float: right;
    display: inherit !important;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.navigation .navbar-collapse {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 56px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 20px;
    z-index: 999;
}
.navigation.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    padding: 10px 0;
    color: #000;
}
.navigation.navbar-dark .navbar-toggler {
    border-color: #fff;
    float: right; 
                  
}}
```

Without the float atrribute the navbar will not responsively move to the given definitions.

Comment: it seems like i am using bootstrap.min.css version 5 file instead of version 3. i changed the file and the menu moved to extreme right as needed. However i would like to keep using version 5 file instead. so what should i do now –